# Hair particle mesh color from vertex color of instancer?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

Is this possible in Eevee?

I'd like to paint some vertex colors on the instancer (NOT an UV mapped texture!) and be able to read that color from where my hair particle spawned and apply that color to a node in my particle object mesh.